# Association of Associations : how to permute level 1 and level 2 keys?

Tags: associations

I have a ragged `Association` of `Association`, say :

```
assoc = Association[
  "1" -> Association["a" -> "x", "b" -> "y"], 
  "2" -> Association[            "b" -> "z", "c" -> "k"]
                   ]
```

I would like to transform it into a `Association` where level 1 and level 2 keys are reversed, that is to say :

```
Association[
      "a" -> Association["1" -> "x"], 
      "b" -> Association["1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"],
      "c" -> Association[            "2" -> "k"]
           ]
```

My solution is :

```
keysExplodedList = Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[Reverse[#2] -> #1] &, assoc, {2}]][[2, 1]]
groupedLevel1 = GroupBy[#[[1, 1]] &] @ keysExplodedList
groupedLevel2 = GroupBy[#[[1, 2]] &] /@ groupedLevel1
result = Map[#[[1, 2]] &, groupedLevel2, {2}]
```

> <|"a" -> <|"1" -> "x"|>, "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>,   "c" ->
>   <|"2" -> "k"|>|>

Is there something more elegant ?

Comment: @WReach I have Mathematica 10.0.1

Comment: My solution could be more concisely rewritten as : `(Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2 -> #1] &, assoc, {2}]][[2, 1]] //
   GroupBy[{#[[1, 2]] &, #[[1, 1]] &}])[[All, All, 1, 2]]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Mathematica* 10.1 almost supports this operation directly:

```
assoc // Query[Transpose]

(*
<| "a" -> <|"1" -> "x", "2" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"]|>,
   "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>,
   "c" -> <|"1" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"], "2" -> "k"|>
|>
*)
```

All that remains is to delete the unwanted `Missing` elements:

```
assoc // Query[Transpose] // DeleteMissing[#, 2]&

(*
<| "a" -> <|"1" -> "x"|>,
   "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>, 
   "c" -> <|"2" -> "k"|>
|>
*)
```

We can see that `Query` uses the undocumented function `` GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose `` to do the heavy-lifting:

```
Query[Transpose] // Normal

(* GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose *)

assoc // GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose

(*
<| "a" -> <|"1" -> "x", "2" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"]|>,
   "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>,
   "c" -> <|"1" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "c"], "2" -> "k"|>
|>
*)
```

**An Imperative Solution**

The words "elegant" and "imperative" rarely appear together these days, but an imperative solution can express the transposition directly:

```
Module[{r = <| |>}
, Do[r = Merge[{r, <| j -> <| i -> assoc[[i, j]] |> |>}, Association]
  , {i, Keys[assoc]}
  , {j, Keys[assoc[[i]]]}
  ]
; r
]

(*
<| "a" -> <|"1" -> "x"|>,
   "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>, 
   "c" -> <|"2" -> "k"|>
|>
*)
```

A *ScanIndexed* operator would come in handy here (the undocumented one in `` GeneralUtilities` `` is not, well, general enough).

Comment: A little less typing: `DeleteMissing[Query[Transpose] @ assoc, 2]`

Comment: @m_goldberg Never thought of `DeleteMissing` for the `DeleteCases`... updated and thanks.

Comment: `//Query[Transpose]` is very interesting if `Transpose` can be used in its general form : `Transpose[#,{n1,n2,n3...}]&` (when there are more than 2 levels of `Association`). I suppose it is the case, but it is not documented.

Comment: @andre Alas, the general form of `Transpose` does not presently work on associations -- whether specified directly or after being interpreted by `Query`.

Answer (score 4):

Not as nice as what WReach posted but this is what I came up with:

```
GroupBy[
  Join @@ Thread /@ Normal //@ assoc,
  {First@*Last, First}
][[All, All, 1, 2, 2]]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"1" -> "x"|>, "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>, "c" -> <|"2" -> "k"|>|>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another version, using `KeyValueMap` (needs 10.1):

```
regroup = 
  Composition[
    Map[Association],
    GroupBy[First -> Last],
    Flatten,
    Normal,
    KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, Map[k -> # &, v]]]
  ];
```

So that

```
regroup @ assoc

(* <|"a" -> <|"1" -> "x"|>, "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>, "c" -> <|"2" -> "k"|>|> *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DeleteMissing /@ GeneralUtilities`AssociationTranspose[assoc]
```

> <|a-><|1->x|>,b-><|1->y,2->z|>,c-><|2->k|>|>

---

I have not noted WReach have mentioned this method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86498/21532).But I think this is a bug behavior in function `Transpose` when it process `Association`.And I have report it to *Wolfram Research* before this.And there is workaround to avoid this bug

```
DeleteMissing /@ Normal[Transpose[Dataset[assoc]]]
```

> <|a-><|1->x|>,b-><|1->y,2->z|>,c-><|2->k|>|>

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

```
assoc // Query[ Transpose /* Map[ DeleteMissing ] ]
```

> <|"a" -> <|"1" -> "x"|>, "b" -> <|"1" -> "y", "2" -> "z"|>, 
>    "c" -> <|"2" -> "k"|>|>