# Long associations of short associations or the inverse, which one should I use?

Tags: associations, data-structures

I don't have enough experiences of using `Association` or `Dataset`, and when operating with nested associations I meet the following choices.

Consider a two-level association to store `member`s with several `property`s, and `Length@member` is much larger than `Length@property`. The `member` keys will be added/deleted by other functions, while the `property` keys are fixed.

**Question1: Should I use long assoc of short assoc, or short of long? Which one is recommended?** (I guess long of short is better.)

To be concrete,

```
max=100;
level1=4;
level2=10;

data[1]=Association@Table[
    "property"<>ToString@j->
        Association@Table[
            "member"<>ToString@i->Table[RandomInteger[max],RandomInteger[i]],
            {i,1,level2}
        ],
    {j,1,level1}
]
```

generates a $4\times 10$ association like

```
<|member1-><|property1->{},property2->{66},property3->{},property4->{58,26,10,49}|>,member2-><|property1->{5},property2->{17},property3->{12,47},property4->{44,82}|>,member3-><|property1->{},property2->{5},property3->{35},property4->{65,67}|>,member4-><|property1->{18},property2->{95},property3->{38},property4->{57,47,64,14}|>,member5-><|property1->{43},property2->{71,43},property3->{},property4->{85,6,75}|>,member6-><|property1->{},property2->{53,21},property3->{},property4->{12,65,83}|>,member7-><|property1->{},property2->{51},property3->{7},property4->{}|>,member8-><|property1->{},property2->{},property3->{41,90},property4->{}|>,member9-><|property1->{},property2->{82,32},property3->{60,94},property4->{73,18,48}|>,member10-><|property1->{},property2->{3},property3->{80,83,78},property4->{37,1,56,66}|>|>
```

```
assoc//Dataset
```

[image]

**Question1`: Is there a standard/recommended function to `Transpose` nested associations?**

This can be easily done like `assoc//Dataset//Transpose//Normal` and is discussed before, e.g. [Association of Associations : how to permute level 1 and level 2 keys?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86492/86893). But since it's a bit old, what is the current status of this question? Which way is more efficient?

**Question2: how to protect `Values` against modification?**

Now the `Values` are actually list, set or some other data structure. Suppose there are some functions to modify them like `add/delete/reset`, like

```
add//Attributes={HoldFirst};
add[assoc_,member_,property_][list_]:=
    Module[{},
        assoc[member,property]=
            Join[assoc[member,property],list];
    ];
```

I want some `Values` in `assoc` to be protected against `add`, and `add` should be like

```
add//Attributes={HoldFirst};
add[assoc_,member_,property_][list_]:=
    Module[{},
        checkProtection[assoc,member,property];
        assoc[member,property]=
            Join[assoc[member,property],list];
    ];
```

So I need some place to store the protected triplets `assoc,member,property` and there are at least two choices:

- save them into `Values` like

```
assoc["member1","property1"]=<|"data"->mylist,"protected"->True|>
```

In this way `assoc` is a three-level association.

- save them into a new symbol like

```
protected//Attributes={HoldFirst};
protected[assoc]^={{"member1","property1"},...}
```

Which one is better?

Comment: I would suggest that you ask these questions via separate posts. For example: `Is there a standard/recommended function to Transpose nested (ragged) associations?` could be a question on its own if presented with a minimal example. Or you may choose to wait for an answer. Regards.

Comment: @syed Thanks for the suggestion. I'll split the question if there is no answer.